# How to insert value into tkinter entry without curly brackets or additional symbols?

Tags: python, tkinter

So my issue is I'm creating a form and currently I need entries into the tk.Entry to be able to be saved and loaded. I have it to the point where it works, however any entries with multiple words are treated as tuples and when loaded appear as {what's this for?} in the entry box and when saved again it becomes {{what's this for?}} etc.
I've considered using the print command to get the tuple to a string value, but I'm not sure how to do that in this instance.

p.s. If anyone who could tell me how to replace text added when loaded instead of adding, that would be great.

```
def ldload():
    f=open(ldcreds, 'r')
    content = f.readlines()
    l = [x.strip() for x in content] 
    ldsplitlists = [i.split(", ") for i in l]
    Characterentx, Playerentx = ldsplitlists
    Characterent.insert(0, Characterentx)
    Playerent.insert(0, Playerentx)
```

and here is how I save it if it will help

```
def ldsave():
with open(ldcreds, 'w') as f:
        f.write(Characterent.get()) 
        f.write('\n') 
        f.write(Playerent.get()) 
        f.write('\n')
```

yes I do close it, I just left out most of the variables.

I appreciate all your help, let me know if I am missing something

Comment: `yes I do close it`... a `with open` statement does that for you.

Comment: Please rewrite your code to have hard-coded strings that we can see, but which still illustrate the problem. What is Characterentx and Playerentx, are they lists? Typically you will see the curly braces if you try to insert a list into an entry widget.

Comment: Characterentx are the loaded strings from the text file, but whenever someone enters two or more words, it turns it into a list, or maybe a touple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a simple program that will take in 3 fields and save them to a file called `test_text` in your main directory.

That same file can be used to load to each field through the use of some if statements when the load button is pressed.

This should be a good example to assist you with your problem.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = parent
        self.save_btn = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Save fields", command= self.ldsave)
        self.save_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
        load_btn = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Load fields", command= self.ldload)
        load_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

        label1 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "First Name: ")
        label1.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)

        label2 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Last Name: ")
        label2.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.entry2.grid(row=2, column=1)

        label3 = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Age: ")
        label3.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.entry3 = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.entry3.grid(row=3, column=1)



    def ldsave(self):
        list_of_entries = [self.entry1.get(), self.entry2.get(), self.entry3.get()]
        with open("./test_text", 'w') as f:
            for item in list_of_entries:
                f.write("{}\n".format(item))

    def ldload(self):
        try:
            with open("./test_text", 'r') as f:
                content = f.readlines()
                content = [x.strip() for x in content]
                for i in range(3):
                    if i == 0:
                        self.entry1.delete(0,tk.END)
                        self.entry1.insert(0,content[i])
                    if i == 1:
                        self.entry2.delete(0,tk.END)
                        self.entry2.insert(0,content[i])
                    if i == 2:
                        self.entry3.delete(0,tk.END)
                        self.entry3.insert(0,content[i])
        except:
            print("File test_text does not exist")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() 
    my_app = App(root)
    tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the curly braces around entries when inserting data into a listboxes by just looping over the tuple ( a tuple was returned in my case from a SQL cursor.fetchall() ) and then selecting the index number for the listbox insert.  That stripped the curly braces from displaying in the listbox.

```
for columns in feedback:
    captured_columns_list.insert(END, columns[0])
```